# VueJS unexpectedly runs a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hello guys specially VueJS devs theres something weird happened. Ill explain it one by one
Full video: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G2ksQsMQ1LB868dg29f8mm4NR_x5GycF/view?fbclid=IwAR1YmYbo3J6jHrY6PHd8E_lxA47VJSXV6G3132_uF6Or3bXv7MbnQbRvKaU

I use datatable and then i use this getDefaultPrice() to manipulate the price because the format of my price is like this ("65;75") to return the first value to PHP 65.00

then once i click the add to cart button please see image for codes the getDefaultPrice() also executed.
and I received an error "price.split is not a function" I tried to console.log the function and it really runs it without calling it in my add_to_cart();

```
<td>
   <p>{{getDefaultPrice(product.price)}}</p>
   </td>
   <td>
   <button
      class="btn main_bg_color add_to_cart_btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal"
      @click="add_to_cart(product)"
   >
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart
   </button>
</td>

add_to_cart(product) {
   this.modal_data = [];
   this.modal_data.push(product) 
   this.modal_data[0].variation = this.modal_data[0].variation.split(';');
   this.modal_data[0].price = this.modal_data[0].price.split(';');
   this.modal_data[0].drinks_price = this.modal_data[0].drinks_price.split(';');
   this.modal_data[0].drinks = this.modal_data[0].drinks.split(';');
},
getDefaultPrice(price) {
   console.log("test")
   var price_arr = price.split(";");
   var default_price = parseFloat(price_arr[0]);
   return "PHP " + default_price.toFixed(2);
},
```

Comment: Try making a computed property that will deliver what `getDefaultPrice` returns.  I think that function will get re-run every render of your component since it is in the component template definition.

Comment: okay ill try thanks :)

Comment: I think it will not work because i use a loop right?

Comment: Where do you use a loop?  I don't see any loops in your code.

Comment: i did not include it because its not related to the issue